# Optimizing multiple IF-IN-SELECT statements in SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, distinct, sql-in

I'm trying to create "flag" columns to see if the primary keys of my main table are in other tables:

```
SELECT
id
,IIF(id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM dbo.example1
    ), 1, 0) AS example1_flag
,IIF(id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id
    FROM dbo.example2
    ), 1, 0) AS example2_flag
--etc.
FROM dbo.main_table
```

I'm doing this multiple times with around ten tables (i.e. creating about ten new columns, each from a different table), and all the tables involved have around a couple million rows. So far, it's a **lot** slower than I expected. Is there a better way to write this query, or is there any way to optimize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use exists 1. The nice thing about it is you dont need to do a distinct you dont need to get all the records, you just need to validate one existence of the id.

```
SELECT
id
,
case when exists (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.example1 b where a.id = b.id) then 1 else 0 end ) AS example1_flag
,case when exists (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.example2 b where a.id = b.id) then 1 else 0 end ) AS example2_flag
--etc.
FROM dbo.main_table a
```

Comment: Still slow, but much faster. Thanks!